# MySQL not catching error

Tags: mysql, sql, exception, exit-code

Why is this code not catching the error when I try to delete a row that doesn't exist?  No matter what parameter I pass in as the name of the row, it always returns "1 row deleted" and doesn't use the exit handlers. which are supposed to catch just this type of error.

```
USE yoga;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS delete_warmup;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_warmup 
(
    warmup_name_param               VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE row_not_found       TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE sql_exception       TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1329
        SET row_not_found = TRUE;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        SET sql_exception = TRUE;

    DELETE FROM warmup
    WHERE warmup_name = warmup_name_param;

    SELECT '1 row was deleted.' AS message;
END;

IF row_not_found = TRUE THEN
    SELECT 'Row not deleted - row not found' AS message;
ELSEIF sql_exception = TRUE THEN
    SHOW ERRORS;
END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL delete_warmup ('Monkey business');
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using an exit handler for a duplicate parameter: http://www.briandunning.com/errors/596  which is 1329 as you specified

Perhaps you should try error code 1011 : http://www.briandunning.com/errors/278

Also, try looking for `NOT FOUND` as well as `SQLException`

Also, try to put the exit handler outside the begin/end clause.

so your `BEGIN` and `END` clause would be

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1011
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, NOT FOUND
BEGIN
        SET row_not_found = TRUE;
        SET sql_exception = TRUE;

    DELETE FROM warmup
    WHERE warmup_name = warmup_name_param;

    SELECT '1 row was deleted.' AS message; 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried this with NOT FOUND, and also with error codes 1011, 1017, 1032, 1065 and 1329.  When I place the exit handlers in the outer BEGIN/END (instead of the nested BEGIN/END), the procedure doesn't work at all, regardless of whether or not the row exists.